# R: Unicode strings

Tags: r, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, codepages

In R for Windows I try to  generate a text file with unicode characters as follows:

```
u="\u044f"
Encoding(u)
# [1] "UTF-8"
cat(u, file='utf8.txt')
Encoding(u)="latin1"
cat(u, file='lat1.txt')
```

Using [MinGW file](https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages), I get:

```
file utf8.txt
# utf8.txt: ASCII text, with no line terminators

file lat1.txt
# lat1.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text, with no line terminators
```

Windows notepad somewhat confirms this:  `utf8.txt` opens with the string `<U+044F>` and `lat1.txt` gives the  actual unicode symbol.

Why does utf8 encoding produce an ASCII text file, while Latin-1 produce UTF-8?

P.S. `sessionInfo()` gives a CP 1252:

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 15063)
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252
```

Comment: Since you're passing `cat` a string instead of a connection made with `file` or the like, you're not actually explicitly specifying what encoding the file should be written with. That doesn't really explain what conversion is actually happening in `cat`, though.

Comment: @alistaire: The default for `file()` in Windows is ASCII text. Why it turns to  UTF-8 for Latin-1 strings and remains ASCII for UTF-8 strings is weird to say the least.